# Vim movements: going to parent

Tags: vim

In Vim, how can I  move to parent/cousine tags in xml files? I'm looking for something similar to:

```
vatat " create a selection for second parent tag with all child elements
```

but in normal mode (eg: go to second parent tag).

Comment: Do you mean parent and *sibling* tags? Cousins, in the genealogical analogy, would be child tags of siblings of a tag's parents.

Comment: @Fred Strictly, both parents and siblings are cousins too (cousin: a relative with whom you share a common ancestor). Common usage does not include them, though. </pedantry>

Comment: Have a look at this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804313/vim-plugin-for-better-xml-html-navigation for inspiration

Comment: I saw it. But it doesn't respond for the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do you want a way to "move" using any text-object motion or just the specific example you've given.
For the first one, just use v at the end

```
vatatv
```

(you can also use o in visual mode, to go to the begining/end of the selection)

If you want a mapping just do (to use ]t and [t)

```
 nnoremap ]t vatatv
 nnoremap [t vatatov
```

or something similar

Comment: I want to move using text-object motion without entering visual mode

Comment: I'm afraid you don't have the choice. What's wrong with that?